# Issue when trying to splice an element from array

Tags: javascript, axios

```html
const data = response.data
console.log(data) let tmp = data.groups_with_selected[7]; 
data.groups_with_selected.splice(7, 2);
data.groups_with_selected.splice(2, 0, tmp);
```

I am trying to splice an element from an array from 7th position, and then insert into 2nd position. But during that process I am successfully able to change the 7th position to 2nd. but issue is after changing the position 7 or 8th position is reflecting in the array.

Comment: I couldn't catch what is the problem, please share an example of your data and what you got after it; and what it should be

Comment: Would you please elaborate on your problem properly? Even the code snippet is not working & doesn't have any real data.

Comment: "but issue is after changing the position 7 or 8th position is reflecting in the array."  what does this mean?

Comment: @Ebay its 7th position, because after splicing the value and inserting in particular position.
At this line data.groups_with_selected.splice(2, 0, tmp);  i am not sure, weather i placed value correctly or not

Comment: If i keep data.groups_with_selected.splice(1, 0, tmp); all the values are displaying correctly. Only if i replace with data.groups_with_selected.splice(2, 0, tmp); then only one value from array is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that:
you should choose the first element of the array which produced by splice by default to become an item and not an array, then insert it to your array at a certain position;

```
const temp = data.groups_with_selected.splice(7,1)[0]
 data.groups_with_selected.splice(2,0,temp )
```

so it will insert the 8th element in the third position;

Comment: Thanks its perfectly working fine. I understood that  first element of array to become an item and not an array, then can u please clarify me 
Why the zero is required :)

Comment: And if i want to replace multiple array values to certain position then can i do like 
const temp = data.groups_with_selected.splice(7,1)(9,1)[0]
data.groups_with_selected.splice(3,0,temp )

Comment: splice by default returns an array so we need to choose the specific element of it, extract it. in your case you need to insert the extracted element by splice, so by putting [0] after it, we extract the item and now it's not array now;

Comment: the second comment, is not obvious to me, sorry, Do you want to do it in one go? if it is the case: you should: data.groups_with_selected.splice(2,0,data.groups_with_selected.splice(7,1)[0])